# python find biggest sequence of zeros in list of lists (recursion)

Tags: python, list, recursion

I need to find the biggest sequence of zeros next to each other (up down left right).
for example in this example the function should return 6

```
mat = [[1,**0**,**0**,3,0],
       [**0**,**0**,2,3,0],
       [2,**0**,**0**,2,0],
       [0,1,2,3,3],]
```

the zeros that i marked as bold should be the answer (6)
the solution should be implemented without any loop (using recursion)

this is what i tried so far

```
def question_3_b(some_list,index_cord):
    y = index_cord[0]
    x = index_cord[1]
    list_of_nums = []
    def main(some_list,index_cord):
        y = index_cord[0]
        x = index_cord[1]
        def check_right(x,y):
            if x + 1 < 0:
                return 0
            if some_list[y][x+1] == 0:
                    main(some_list,(y,x+1))

            else:
                    return 0
        def check_left(x,y):
            if x -1 < 0:
                return 0
            if some_list[y][x - 1] == 0:
                main(some_list,(y, x - 1))

        def check_down(x,y):
            if y + 1 < 0:
                return  0
            try:
                if  some_list[y + 1][x] == 0:

                    main(some_list,(y + 1, x))
            except:
                 print("out of range")
        def check_up(x,y):
            counter_up = 0
            if y - 1 < 0:
                return 0

            if some_list[y - 1][x] == 0:
                counter_up += 1
                main(some_list,(y - 1, x))



        list_of_nums.append((x,y))
        right = check_right(x,y)
        down = check_down(x,y)
        left = check_left(x,y)
        up = check_up(x, y)

    main(some_list,index_cord)
    print(list_of_nums)

question_3_b(mat,(0,1))
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @shaikmoeed i added to the post what i tried

Comment: Look for an algorithm called BFS (Breadth First Search), the general idea shoul be somthing like: for each not marked zero do BFS (this will mark all the adjancet zeros recursively and you can count them there), next go to the next not marked zero and repeat, and so on. In the process you can keep track of the biggest chunk size. BFS is a graph algorithm, but you can treat your matrix as a graph where all positions represents vertices and the adjacent position represents connections.

Comment: The algorithm you're looking for is decribed at [Wikipedia: Flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution #1: classic BFS

As I mention in a comment, you can tackle this problem using BFS (Breadth First Search), it will be something like this:

```py
# This function will give the valid adjacent positions
# of a given position according the matrix size (NxM)
def valid_adj(i, j, N, M):
    adjs = [[i + 1, j], [i - 1, j], [i, j + 1], [i, j - 1]]
    for a_i, a_j in adjs:
        if 0 <= a_i < N and 0 <= a_j < M:
            yield a_i, a_j

def biggest_zero_chunk(mat):
    answer = 0
    N, M = len(mat), len(mat[0])

    # Mark all non zero position as visited (we are not instrested in them)
    mask = [[mat[i][j] != 0 for j in range(M)] for i in range(N)]

    queue = []
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
            if mask[i][j]: # You have visited this position
                continue

            # Here comes the BFS
            # It visits all the adjacent zeros recursively,
            # count them and mark them as visited
            current_ans = 1
            queue = [[i,j]]
            while queue:
                pos_i, pos_j = queue.pop(0)
                mask[pos_i][pos_j] = True
                for a_i, a_j in valid_adj(pos_i, pos_j, N, M):
                    if mat[a_i][a_j] == 0 and not mask[a_i][a_j]:
                        queue.append([a_i, a_j])
                        current_ans += 1
            answer = max(answer, current_ans)
    return answer

mat = [[1,0,0,3,0],
       [0,0,2,3,0],
       [2,0,0,2,0],
       [0,1,2,3,3],]

mat2 = [[1,0,0,3,0],
        [0,0,2,3,0],
        [2,0,0,0,0],  # A slight modification in this row to connect two chunks
        [0,1,2,3,3],]
 
print(biggest_zero_chunk(mat))
print(biggest_zero_chunk(mat2))
```

Output:

```
6
10
```

### Solution #2: using only recursion (no `for` statements)

```py
def count_zeros(mat, i, j, N, M):
    # Base case
    # Don't search zero chunks if invalid position or non zero values
    if i < 0 or i >= N or j < 0 or j >= M or mat[i][j] != 0:
        return 0

    ans = 1        # To count the current zero we start at 1
    mat[i][j] = 1  # To erase the current zero and don't count it again
    ans += count_zeros(mat, i - 1, j, N, M)  # Up
    ans += count_zeros(mat, i + 1, j, N, M)  # Down
    ans += count_zeros(mat, i, j - 1, N, M)  # Left
    ans += count_zeros(mat, i, j + 1, N, M)  # Right
    return ans

def biggest_zero_chunk(mat, i = 0, j = 0, current_ans = 0):
    N, M = len(mat), len(mat[0])

    # Base case (last position of mat)
    if i == N - 1 and j == M - 1:
        return current_ans

    next_j = (j + 1) % M                  # Move to next column, 0 if j is the last one
    next_i = i + 1 if next_j == 0 else i  # Move to next row if j is 0
    ans = count_zeros(mat, i, j, N, M)    # Count zeros from this position
    current_ans = max(ans, current_ans)   # Update the current answer
    return biggest_zero_chunk(mat, next_i, next_j, current_ans) # Check the rest of mat

mat = [[1,0,0,3,0],
       [0,0,2,3,0],
       [2,0,0,2,0],
       [0,1,2,3,3],]

mat2 = [[1,0,0,3,0],
        [0,0,2,3,0],
        [2,0,0,0,0],  # A slight modification in this row to connect two chunks
        [0,1,2,3,3],]

print(biggest_zero_chunk(mat.copy()))
print(biggest_zero_chunk(mat2.copy()))
```

Output:

```
6
10
```

#### Notes:

The idea behind this solution is still BFS (represented mainly in the `count_zeros` function). Also, if you are interested in using the matrix values after this you should call the `biggest_zero_chunk` with a copy of the matrix (because it is modified in the algorithm)

Comment: hey it looks good but , i can't use for loops at all , i need it only using recursion

Comment: Hi, sorry I missed the part of "no loops" when reading the question. I attached another solution, this time purely resursive (no `for` statements).